# python passing dictionary parameter with key

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameter-passing

I want to make a function call with a dictionary like:

```
valueattime(simulaton_01['Temperature_05'], 20)
```

but I always get a syntax error with the following function

```
def valueattime(experiment[key], time):
    ...
```

It works with simple parameters. But for `autocompletion` sake it would be great to pass the parameters in the dictionary-form.

Any ideas?

Comment: `def valueattime(temperature, time): ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass it as a regular argument:

```
def valueattime(temp, time):
    pass

a = {'some_key': 'some_value'}

valueattime(a['some_key], 20)
```

This works!

To supply dictionary items to a function, you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k: valueattime(v) for k, v in a.iteritems()}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the function call!
But I have to figure out, how to work with other keys of the dictionary "a" within the function valueattime.

Comment: @Martin_K hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the function signature to pass parameters directly from the dictionary:

```
def valueattime(temperature, time):
    ...

valueattime(simulation_01['temp_05'], 20)  # this works just fine
```

Python will first run `simulation_01['temp_05']` to retrieve the value, and pass it as `temperature` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Remember it'a all objects...

```
def valueattime(temp, time)
```

Defines a method taking two input parameters, two object which are referred to by the **names** `temp` and `time`

`simulation_01['temp_05']` return an object, so calling your method like: `valueattime( simulation_01['temp_05'], 20 )` should be what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you... it works (but ;-))...
within the function `valueattime` I want to do some operations with other elements of simulation_01, like `numpy.where(simulation_01['mdot_01'] == 0)`. But I think this is not possible?

Comment: actually it should work